# Textview Strike with different color

Tags: android, textview

want to add textview which will have black text color and Strike with different color

for strile using

```
txtview.setPaintFlags(txtview.getPaintFlags()|Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in three ways, by either setting foreground in `TextView`, or setting `PaintFlag` or declaring string as `<strike>your_string</strike>` in `strings.xml`. For example,

**Through PaintFlag**

This is simplest method you just have to set strikethrough flag on your TextView as,

`yourTextView.setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);`

it will strike through your TextView.

**Through foreground drawable**

You can also strike through your TextView by setting a background as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="line">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Now, you just have to set above drawable in your TextView as background.

**Through strings.xml**

In this method, you have to declare your string in strings.xml as strike through as,

```
<string name="strike_line"> <strike>This line is strike throughed</strike></string>
```

**Note**

But I recommend you to strike through your TextView by setting foreground drawable. Because through drawable you can easily set your strike through line color(as like I setted as red color in above example) or size or any other style property. While in other two methods default textcolor is strike through color.

Comment: for drawable its coming behind textview not above text

Comment: Yup because you are setting it as a `background`, you have to set it as `foreground`.

Comment: Yeah, that's why you have to use it in a XML, as `android:foreground`.